# How can I align text with bootstrap glyph-icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My boxes are lined up but the 33 is not centered, https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqjwsx/

```
<div class="LargeStarBox">
<span class="LargeStar glyphicon glyphicon-star "></span>
<span class="LargeStar glyphicon glyphicon-star "></span>
<span class="LargeStar glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
<span class="LargeStar glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
<span class="LargeStar glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty "></span>
<span class="LargeStarFont glyphicon ">33</span>
</div>
```

// css

```
.LargeStarBox {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

    .LargeStar {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #D9AB4D;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-top: 7px;
    }

    .LargeStarFont {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: blue;
      margin-left: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      vertical-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an outer container and an inner container to vertically align middle the number text. The outer container has display: table; and the inner container has display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; (vertical-align: center is not a valid CSS property).

HTML

```
<span class="numberFont">
    <span class="number-outer">
      <span class="number-inner">33</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.numberFont {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  height: 22px;
}

.number-outer {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 3px;
}

.number-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I also made some small CSS changes to match the size of the star boxes:

https://jsfiddle.net/rmurph46/7ed4u378/2/